# React/TypeScript: How should I handle this style of component composition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm very new to `typescript` so please bear with me.

I'm trying to convert this `react` component:

```js
interface ButtonProps {...}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  href,
  value
  as = 'button',
  ...props
}) => {
  const Element = href ? 'a' : as;
  // ...

  return (
    <Element {...props}>
      <span>{value || children}</span>
    </Element>
  );
};
```

But I'm getting the following error on the `<Element>` element:

```sh
JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

I can satisfy the compiler by typing `Element` with `any` but that feels dirty.

How should I be approaching this pattern from a `TS` point of view?

Thanks!

Comment: also, React element !== React component. Use a component like: `<Component/>` and an element like: `<div>{element}</div>`

Comment: Use if else in return statement. if(href) return <a ...> </a> else return <button ...></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ElementType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L72)

```
interface ButtonProps {
  ...
  as?: ElementType
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! I knew it would be something nice and simple